# iOS confusion post release of app on the iStore

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I set my app to only support iOS 6.0 and above. Epic Fail, the app isn't that complex, could someone help me figure out the correct settings to allow user with iOS 4.3 and above to use my app.

**Current App Settings which are live**

Project: AppProject > Base SDK=latest iOS 6.0, iOS Deployment Target = 6.0

Target:  AppProject > iOS Deployment Target = 6.0

Issue: I have tired to run my code using the 4.3 emulator however the app appears black after the splash screen appears. Any ideas what this could be? im confused with this...

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your deployment target 4.3 but its ok to use the 6.0 SDK. Why it is black when you run the app could be a bigger problem. When you upload the build to itunes connect it will tell you the minimum version required so you can double check you set the deployment target correctly.

Comment: Oh I think your problem is you can't use storyboards in 4.3. Can you run in 5.0? Maybe you should just go from 5.0 on

Comment: No not running with 5.0, i changed the target to 5.0 and i still get Users/mauriceboland/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/1E8A38CD-31DD-49C0-8E65-13D99C017191/Trips.app  theres nothing in that location not sure what that is

Comment: Before moving forward I would do a clean, close xcode/simulator and rebuild from scratch to ios5.0. I'm not sure why you aren't seeing it there

Comment: could i just go with 5.0 and upload to the iStore? ha

Comment: If you use Storyboards I think you have to set deployment target to 5.1, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Some guy said this not sure what he means tho.

It seems that using ios 6 base localization moves the storyboard file, so ios 5 doesn't find the file. Using english localization instead fixed the issue for me.